# Determine whether a row is selected in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, loops, datagridview

I'm looping through a DataGridView, and I need to do this :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count - 2; i)
 {
    // if the row is selected
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: is there a question that goes with that? also - should `i` change at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of missing context, but I *think* you mean just:

```
var rows = DGV.Rows;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count - 2; i++)
{
    if (rows[i].Selected)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

[DataGridView.SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DGV.SelectedRows.Contains(DGW.Rows[i]))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectedItem = DataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;
if(selectedItem>0){
   //do something here
}
```